# Javascript RegExp : split by comma with filtering excess white-space

Tags: javascript, regex

This is my input string:

```
var str = 'tags:  JavaScript, Markdown,   Web  , programming   skill  ';
```

At first I filter the 'tags:' part by

```
var tags = str.match(/^tags:\s{0,}(.{1,})/);
```

Then the string is

```
'JavaScript, Markdown,   Web  , programming   skill  '
```

How could I get the result by RegExp-match.

```
['JavaScript', 'Markdown', 'Web', 'programming skill']
```

---

Thank everyone.

Comment: Yes. you answer completely accord my request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to do `string.replace` and then `string.split` because your input contains more than one spaces at the middle.

```
> var str = 'tags:  JavaScript, Markdown,   Web  , programming   skill  ';
> var res = str.replace(/tags:\s*|\s*$|( ) +/g, '$1');
> res.split(/\s*,\s*/)
[ 'JavaScript',
  'Markdown',
  'Web',
  'programming skill' ]
```

`tags:\s*|\s*$|( ) +` matches the leading `tags` string along with the following spaces or the spaces which are at the end of the string or captures the single space at the middle and the spaces following that single space are matched. Replacing all the matched characters with the chars inside group index 1 would be  resulted in removing trailing spaces, the string `tags spaces`  and the two or more spaces at the middle would be turned into one.

[DEMO for the String.replace Part](https://regex101.com/r/vQ6jE6/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
tags:\s+|\s*,\s+
```

Split by this.Remove an `empty element` later.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/qB0jV1/4